# Unable to get view controller size. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, sprite-kit

I'm new to Swift and I'm trying to use the following method to create an SKSpriteNode in my GameScene.swift:

```
    var longChainsaw = ChainsawMaker.longChainsawCreator()
```

The problem is I need to get the size of the GameScene view from the ChainsawMaker class.  This is what I have in ChainsawMaker.swift:

```
import SpriteKit

class ChainsawMaker: SKScene {

class func longChainsawCreator () -> SKSpriteNode {

    //LONG CHAINSAW
    let longChainsawWidth = size.width/3
```

The error occurs with size.width/3 which is "ChainsawMaker.Type does not have a member named size"

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're calling the class func `longChainsawCreator()` without having initiated an instance of `ChainsawMaker`.

According to the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKScene/size), `size` exists as an instance variable, not a class variable

Comment: I see.  I changed it to the following `class ChainsawMaker: SKSpriteNode {
    
    func longChainsawCreator2 () -> SKSpriteNode {`  But I get the following error: "PhysicsBody: Could not create physics body."  What is strange is that I do in fact see my physics body where it should be and my sprites are interacting with it properly.  Any idea how to get rid of this error?

Comment: That's a different question, I think you opened another SO question for this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608790/could-not-create-physics-body-swift. I'll reply over there. Feel free to clos e this question